# Round A Variable Autohotkey

Tags: variables, rounding, autohotkey

I've been trying to round a variable for the past hour and cannot figure out how to do so.

```
average_load = 1.234
average_load := Round(%average_load%)
```

It keeps saying that it contains an illegal character.

Comment: Remove the percent signs. Always mind the difference between [traditional value assignments and expressions](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm).

Comment: Ohh I see. I wasn't sure if it was because it was a function or something. But I see it works like a typical expression.

Comment: Did you get it working? It would be nice if you posted your working script as an answer and accepted, so that others with the same problem can profit.

Comment: Sure thing, I thought you would do it, since you already gave the 4 word suggestion :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Functions are always expression capable and thus variables do not need to be quoted.**

```
average_load = 1.234
average_load := Round(average_load)
```

What is expression capable? See [examples of Variables and Expressions](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm).

It is same difference as `:=` is expression ready so variables do not need to be declared whereas for `=` the expressions must be declared with surrounding `%` or a leading `%`.

Comment: To be exact, the way you assign a function's return value to a variable (incidentally using `:=`) has nothing to do with how you pass parameters to a function. Example: If we call a function without the need to get its return value, we don't use `:=` at all...e.g. `WriteToSomeFile("hello")`. So the gist is actually: Functions always and exlusively accept expressions as parameters. How we retrieve the return value is a whole nother story.

Comment: @MCL Thanks, I totally emphasized the wrong thing. Revised.